# Applying statistics methods on numpy arrays: unexpected results

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, statistics, python-internals

Please explain.

```
import statistics
x = [0,1]
statistics.mean(x) 
## 0.5
```

**But:**

```
import numpy 
import statistics
x = numpy.array([0,1])
statistics.mean(x) 
## 0
```

I'm pretty sure it's a basic, well-known, over-discussed issue: please link to a duplicate, as I couldn't find one.

Comment: I know ``numpy`` has its own ``numpy.mean()`` function, ``scipy.stats`` has ``scipy.stats.mean()`` I'm interested here in why I can't seem to combine ``numpy`` with ``statistics``.

Comment: wow 3 downvotes in 3 seconds.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding the downvotes. Can somebody explain?

Comment: @PatrickT, upvote from me. This is a good question. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#module-statistics) are not clear that only specified types are permitted (list vs 3rd party list-like structures).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is there is a conversion method in the `statistics` module which checks if a data type is a subclass of `int`. This works for `int`, but not for `np.int32`.

```
import statistics
from fractions import Fraction

a = statistics._convert(Fraction('1/2'), int)       # 0.5
b = statistics._convert(Fraction('1/2'), np.int32)  # 0

def _convert(value, T):
    """Convert value to given numeric type T."""
    if type(value) is T:
        return value

    #### THIS BIT WORKS FOR int BUT not for np.int32 ###
    if issubclass(T, int) and value.denominator != 1:
        T = float

    try:
        return T(value)
    except TypeError:
        if issubclass(T, Decimal):
            return T(value.numerator)/T(value.denominator)
        else:
            raise
```

---

Therefore, you can either use `statistics` with a list, or `numpy` with an array:

1. Use `statistics.mean([0, 1])`; or
2. Use `np.mean(np.array([0, 1]))`, or `np.array([0, 1]).mean()`.

Comment: Okay, so I should do ``numpy.array([0,1.])``? I've been reading that ``statistics`` is designed for high precision and ``numpy`` for large data and speed. Is it unfortunate that they don't do so well for a two-data problem involving 0 and 1 (rhetorical question) or is it a design choice? Thanks for your great answer!